# Problem with PHP embedding into HTML for picture choice

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade

I can't seem to control the action I want. If the first image is empty, I want the placeholder of the appropriate gender to be chosen.

```
     <div class="image-box">
          <img src="{{config('url.media')}}u/{{ $agent['user_id'] }}/150@2x.jpg" style="width:100%" class="image_main" alt="">
          @if(empty('image_main'))
            @if($agent['gender'] == 'Mr')
              <img src="{{('../assets/male-placeholder.png')}}" style="width:100%" alt="">
            @elseif($agent['gender'] == 'Ms')
              <img src="{{('../assets/female-placeholder.png')}}" style="width:100%" alt="">
            @else($agent['gender'] == 'Mx')
              <img src="{{('../assets/non-binary-placeholder.png')}}" style="width:100%" alt="">
            @endif
          @endif
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't know laravel and the template engine it uses but it seems to me like you are calling `empty()` on the string `image_main` and that would always return false so your block of code underneath that won't get executed.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to do `empty($agent['image_main'])`

Comment: @KodosJohnson I've tried wrapping the image main in and if/else statement (as !empty) but it is not giving me the placeholders on the ones with no 'image_main'

Comment: Please see my previous comment. Are you sure you didn't mean to do `empty($agent['image_main'])`? You are calling empty() on a string, not a variable where you have stored the image main.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Ideally, I would do that. But the image isn't stored in the app's database. It's stored on a cloud server.

Comment: I'm trying to call the action on the image after it's already called down

Comment: Or would that even matter?

Comment: Do you store a value in the database that shows if the image exists? Or do you just check to see if the image is available in the cloud server. Either way, you need to store in a variable and call `empty()` on the variable. Not on a string "image_main" as you are doing. Calling `empty('image_main')` is pointless as it will always be false.